# The system cannot find the file specified in terminal

Tags: makefile, command, clang

when i tryed to use make command in terminal he give me this massege. notice that the name of file is "name"

```
cc     name.c   -o name
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, cc name.c -o name, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [<builtin>: name] Error 2
```

its what i tryed to run :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "cs50.h"
#include "cs50.c"

int main(void)
{
    float money = get_float("how much money do you have ?  ");
    printf("%f !  you relly rich", money);
}
```

its started with another massege

and i fix it with downloading mingw compiler, powershell 7.0 and chocolatey

now if i want to run a proggram i need to save the file then run it in output then run it in terminal with (./)
so what should i do ?

Excuse me for the weak language because it is not my mother tongue and I have been working on it

Comment: This message means that make is trying to run a program `cc` and there isn't one found: either it doesn't exist at all or it's not on your PATH.  On a POSIX system such as GNU/Linux the C compiler is traditionally called `cc`.  Since you're running on Windows, your compiler is called something else.  You'll have to figure out what that is, and set `CC = <compiler>` in your makefile, if you want this to work.